# How to create a blank space in layout xml

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout

I am using TableLayout to format a 3x2 table, which starts with one attribute name in each cell and one empty TextView that will be edited to contain a value during runtime. I want the first column to start at the left margin of the screen, and the next column to start in the middle of the screen. The empty TextViews have their text set to "   *there are ~10 spaces here*     ", but the blank spaces don't show up in the Graphical Editor.

How can I create a TextView that holds blank spaces?

Here is my xml file right now:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="166dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datetext"
            android:text="@string/date" ></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heartratetext"
            android:text="@string/heart_rate" ></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heart_rate"
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <TextView
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timetext"
            android:text="@string/time" ></TextView>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SDNNtext"
            android:text="@string/SDNN" ></TextView>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SDNN"
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>


    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/durationtext"
            android:text="@string/duration" ></TextView>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SDANNtext"
            android:text="@string/SDANN" ></TextView>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SDANN"
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <TextView
            android:text="@string/empty" ></TextView>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your way of reasoning is incorrect. You should concentrate on giving empty TextView a proper width and fullfiling it with a given amount of spaces is not the correct way. If you want to give each of your TextViews in a TableRow a given width which will be constant try to use LinearLayout and layout_weight attributes. For example if each TextView should take 1/4 of width of the row than:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/datetext"
            android:text="@string/date" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:text="@string/empty" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/heartratetext"
            android:text="@string/heart_rate" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/heart_rate"
            android:text="@string/empty" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Edit: It's also worth mantioned that you have to set android:stretchColumns="*" attribute in your TableLayout for that solution to work correctly.